# TikZ smooth plot, retrieves points along the path in parametric way

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have a certain curve, whose "control" points I specify using pre-set coordinates.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (42,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,42);
    \draw plot[smooth] coordinates{(A) (B) (C)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now we can imagine that this is some trajectory and some "object" has been at coordinate `(A)` at time `t = 0` and has arrived at `(C)` at time `t = 1`. I would like to know if it is possible to specify a certain spot along this trajectory, saying `t = 0.5` for example, that would effectively mean "halfway through" `(A)` and `(B)`? I need this functionality so that I can specify a "naturally-looking" shape, and only then draw things on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using path decorations:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    define coord/.style 2 args={
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position #2 with {\coordinate (#1);},
      },
      postaction=decorate,
    }
  ]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (5,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (0,5);
  \draw[blue, define coord={P}{0.2}, define coord={I}{0.5},
              define coord={Q}{0.75}]
    plot[smooth] coordinates { (A) (B) (C) };
  \fill[red] (P) circle[radius=2pt] node[black, below] {At time $0.2$};
  \node[red!80!black, pin=20:$I$] at (I) {middle};
  \node[above right] at (Q) {At $3/4$ of the curve};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you noted, in a given path, the style must be used with increasing coordinates, otherwise the points aren't placed as expected.

Comment: I accept the answer. The only caveat is that the ratios need to be specified in increasing order, otherwise the engine gets somehow confused.

Comment: @Ilonpilaaja You're right, thanks for pointing it out. I've slightly expanded the example and mentioned the “increasing order” constraint for coordinates.